# SuperUser tag image truncated

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

I just got done posting an answer (to [this](//superuser.com/questions/15090) question) in SuperUser and noticed that one of the tags seems to have lost its edge in the image:

*missing image removed*

I'm not sure if that is related to the length of the tag itself or maybe just a rendering issue. I found this in Chrome. It didn't duplicate itself in IE, but I'm also noticing that IE renders "boxed" tages and Chrome is displaying rounded edges.

Comment: Whoah, that kind of messes with your head when you glance at it. I'll do a better screenshot next time.

Comment: It's not like that in Opera, so it's Chrome-ish-related-ness.

Comment: 2 1/2 years later... Now seeing it in Opera 11.62 on Ubuntu 11.10  !! http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4824/favorite-ignore-tags-right-hand-side-of-box-is-cut-off-at-line-ends-in-opera-o

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug in Chrome - I get it too, in Safari 4!

Comment: Oh if only they weren't using the same Webkit base.

Comment: @random - they are using the same WebKit base, yes, but don't you want your site to work in all browsers, bugs or not?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Chrome, not us